# How to get (Retrieve) data from SQlite database in Flask using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, html, database, sqlite, flask

I have a form in my flask application that collects emails, usernames, and phone numbers. I have stored them all in the SQLite database using flask sqlalchemy. Let's say my database looks like the following:

```
Email                    Username                     Phone Number
James@yahoo.com           James                          123456789
 Jane@yahoo.com            Jane                          987654321
```

I have an HTML file and I would like to display data there. What I have is :

```
> @app.route("/Display") 
  def Display():
     # Here I want to get all data from the database
     # like this data=get from database 
     return render_template('Display.html', data=data)
```

I would like to know can anyone tell me how to retrieve data or get the data from database using flask sqlalchemy ORM.  I know query.filter_by can be used to filter according to a username or email or phone number. However, how can I get the whole table (like in a form to pass to render_template? like in HTML page I want to loop through data and use data.username or data.email)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to retrieve everything

```
data = Model.query.all()
```

Where `model` is the name of your model. 
This returns a list of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the data by a specific value:

```
data = Model.query.filter_by(attribute=value)
```

You can add  `.all()` if you want to get all instances of your Model matching the value.

If you want to filter by the ID of the data:

```
data = Model.get_or_404(dataID)
```